# How to get sum of amount from multiple tables?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have three (3) tables which l want to get the sum total of amount from it.

**OrderDetail**

| Product | Amount | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | 2023-09-01 |
| Orange | 5 | 2023-10-01 |

**LearnerDetail**

| Name | Amount | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tutor | 30 | 2023-09-01 |
| Levy | 10 | 2023-09-01 |

**StoreDetail**

| Name | Amount | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Loc A | 5 | 2023-09-01 |
| Loc B | 5 | 2023-10-01 |

This is what I've tried.

```sql
SELECT 
    DATEPART(m, orderdate) AS Month,
    Total = (SELECT SUM(amount)
             FROM orderdetail) +
            (SELECT SUM(amount)
             FROM learnerdetail) +  
            (SELECT SUM(amount)
             FROM storedetail)
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(m, orderdate)
```

Expected output

| OrderDate | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-01 | 55 |
| 2023-10-01 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution involves leveraging the `WITH` clause to create a temporary table that unifies the desired data from various sources `(Common Table Expression)`. Subsequently, we employ the `SELECT` statement with the `GROUP BY` clause to obtain the desired aggregate values.

```sql
WITH mytable
     AS (SELECT amount,
                order_date
         FROM   order_details
         UNION ALL
         SELECT amount,
                order_date
         FROM   learner_details
         UNION ALL
         SELECT amount,
                order_date
         FROM   store_details)
SELECT Sum(amount),
       Month(order_date)
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY Month(order_date);
```

> Here the SQL query combines data from three tables (order_details, learner_details, store_details) into a common table. It then calculates the sum of the "amount" column for each month, grouping the results accordingly.

Here you can use `GROUP  BY EOMONTH(order_date)` which is probably better, especially if you have more than 12 months of data.

Comment: You should use `UNION ALL`, and not `UNION`   (see: [What is the difference between UNION and UNION ALL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all))

Comment: @Luuk Thanks i forgot about the duplicates :-)

Comment: @Sanmeet I getting this error from your code ' 
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.'

Comment: @User_K47 Okay this issue is caused due to no. of cols mismatch ! To resolve you can manually select the cols from each select statment and then perform unions ... finally cte and hence select query

Comment: @User_K47 Updated answer .. btw you can check more about the error on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299390/error-union-operator-must-have-an-equal-number-of-expressions-when-using-cte)

Comment: @Sanmeet Alright. Thanks

Comment: `GROUP  BY EOMONTH(order_date)` is probably better, especially if you have more than 12 months of data.

Comment: @Charlieface Didn't knew about it ! Thanks